# Cant hide playlist html video

Tags: css, html, video

Got this script and it works fine, the problem is that it show´s the video on the playlist, ive tried to visibility:hidden; and display:none; and it doesnt work, anyone knows how to hide this?

```js
var video_player = document.getElementById("video_player");
video = video_player.getElementsByTagName("video")[0],
  video_links = video_player.getElementsByTagName("figcaption")[0],
  source = video.getElementsByTagName("source"),
  link_list = [],
  vidDir = "http://demosthenes.info/assets/videos/",
  currentVid = 0,
  allLnks = video_links.children,
  lnkNum = allLnks.length;
video.removeAttribute("controls");
video.removeAttribute("poster");

(function() {
  function playVid(index) {
    video_links.children[index].classList.add("currentvid");
    source[1].src = vidDir + link_list[index] + ".webm";
    source[0].src = vidDir + link_list[index] + ".mp4";
    currentVid = index;
    video.load();
    video.play();
  }

  for (var i = 0; i < lnkNum; i++) {
    var filename = allLnks[i].href;
    link_list[i] = filename.match(/([^\/]+)(?=\.\w+$)/)[0];
    (function(index) {
      allLnks[i].onclick = function(i) {
        i.preventDefault();
        for (var i = 0; i < lnkNum; i++) {
          allLnks[i].classList.remove("currentvid");
        }
        playVid(index);
      }
    })(i);
  }
  video.addEventListener('ended', function() {
    allLnks[currentVid].classList.remove("currentvid");
    if ((currentVid + 1) >= lnkNum) {
      nextVid = 0
    } else {
      nextVid = currentVid + 1
    }
    playVid(nextVid);
  })

  video.addEventListener('mouseenter', function() {
    video.setAttribute("controls", "true");
  })

  video.addEventListener('mouseleave', function() {
    video.removeAttribute("controls");
  })

  var indexOf = function(needle) {
    if (typeof Array.prototype.indexOf === 'function') {
      indexOf = Array.prototype.indexOf;
    } else {
      indexOf = function(needle) {
        var i = -1,
          index = -1;
        for (i = 0; i < this.length; i++) {
          if (this[i] === needle) {
            index = i;
            break;
          }
        }
        return index;
      };
    }
    return indexOf.call(this, needle);
  };
  var focusedLink = document.activeElement;
  index = indexOf.call(allLnks, focusedLink);

  document.addEventListener('keydown', function(e) {
    if (index) {
      var focusedElement = document.activeElement;
      if (e.keyCode == 40 || e.keyCode == 39) { // down or right cursor
        var nextNode = focusedElement.nextElementSibling;
        if (nextNode) {
          nextNode.focus();
        } else {
          video_links.firstElementChild.focus();
        }
      }
      if (e.keyCode == 38 || e.keyCode == 37) { // up or left cursor
        var previousNode = focusedElement.previousElementSibling;
        if (previousNode) {
          previousNode.focus();
        } else {
          video_links.lastElementChild.focus();
        }
      }
    }
  });

})();
```

```css
#video_player {
  display: table;
  line-height: 0;
  max-width: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
#video_container {
  position: relative;
}
#video_player div,
#video_player figcaption {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: top;
}
#video_container video {
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  top: 0;
}
#video_player figcaption {
  width: 25%;
}
#video_player figcaption a {
  display: block;
}
#video_player figcaption a {
  opacity: .3;
  transition: 1s opacity;
}
#video_player figcaption a img,
figure video {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
#video_player figcaption a.currentvid,
#video_player figcaption a:hover,
#video_player figcaption a:focus {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<figure id="video_player">
  <div id="video_container">
    <video controls poster="vid-glacier.jpg" autostart>
      <source src="http://thenewcode.com/assets/videos/glacier.webm" type="video/webm" autostart>
        <source src="http://thenewcode.com/assets/videos/glacier.mp4" type="video/mp4" autostart>
    </video>
  </div>
  <figcaption>
    <a href="http://thenewcode.com/assets/videos/lake.mp4" class="currentvid">
      <img src="http://demosthenes.info/assets/images/vid-glacier.jpg" alt="Athabasca Glacier">
    </a>
    <a href="http://thenewcode.com/assets/videos/mountain.mp4">
      <img src="http://demosthenes.info/assets/images/vid-glacier.jpg" alt="Athabasca Glacier">
    </a>
    <a href="http://thenewcode.com/assets/videos/glacier.mp4">
      <img src="http://demosthenes.info/assets/images/vid-glacier.jpg" alt="Athabasca Glacier">
    </a>
  </figcaption>
</figure>
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Try with the parameter `!important`.

Comment: Thats the thing, booth visibility and display work, but visibility leave the empty space and the display hides everything

Comment: Use only one, and if you use visibility and you want to remove the empty space change the height to 0.

Comment: To hide only the video: `#video_container { display: none !important; }`

Comment: But i dont want to hide the video i want to hide the playlist, the figcaption section without hidding the video.

Comment: Ah sorry, in that case is... `#video_player figcaption { display: none !important; }`.

Comment: But in that case it wont show the video_container.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, this CSS should work for you. I've marked all the important items. But before we get to that, lets look at what was wrong. This is what you had:

```
#video_container video {position: absolute; top: 0;}
#video_player figcaption {width: 25%;}
```

The `position`, and its `top`, code were overriding all forms of hiding the playlist. Even if `#video_player figcaption` was set to `display: none;` or `visibility: hidden;` this had no effect on hiding the playlist because of `width: 25%;`. The width was overriding the `display/visibility`, which we all know that `display: none;` should override everything. But the width was still visible because `position: absolute;` from `#video_container video` said "I don't care what everything else says, you're staying put". These things have been fixed. The correct CSS to use is below.

```
#video_player {display: table;
               margin: auto;
               background: #000000;
               width: 500px; /*The space you want occupied.*/
}

#video_container {position: relative;}

#video_player div, #video_player figcaption {display: table-cell; vertical-align: top;}

#video_container video {display: block;
                        width: 100%; /*How big you want the video to be.*/
                        height: ---; /*Whatever you want*/
                        /*width: 350px;*/ /*Use with visible playlist.*/
                        /*height: 100%;*/ /*Use with visible playlist.*/
}

#video_player figcaption {display: none; /*Hides the playlist from view.*/
}

#video_player figcaption a {display: block; opacity: .3; transition: 1s opacity;}
#video_player figcaption a img {width: 100%;}
#video_player figcaption a.currentvid, #video_player figcaption a:hover, #video_player figcaption a:focus {opacity: 1;}
```

Answer (score 0):

New Post: To hide the current video, look at `#video_player figcaption a.currentvid ... a:focus`. Change `opacity: 1;` to `opacity: 0;`, add `visibility: hidden;` (which will hide the area, but not remove the space that it occupies), or add `display: none;` (which is the best solution). If you want to have the playlist appear on several pages, then make sure to place `class="currentvid"` in the correct `<a>` each time.

---

Old Post: You need to add `display: none;` or `display: none !important;` to `#video_container`. The problem is that you might. To have `display: none;` work correctly, move `#video_container` below `#video_container video`. If you want everything to stay where it is, then use display: none !important;` which will override everything else and hide your video.

```
#video_container {
  position: relative;
  display: none !important;
}
```

Comment: But i dont want to hide the video i want to hide the playlist, the figcaption section without hidding the video

Comment: Oh, sorry. Read the question wrong. I updates the post above with a few correct solutions.

Comment: but if i add display:none; the video disapear, the playlist section wont be seen in any page is just to specify to the script the videos to play in loop nothing more. i only need to show the video_container in a loop from the list in figcaption.

Comment: Are you wanting the selected video on the playlist to hide when it is playing?

Comment: I want all playlist videos to be hidden

Comment: Well using `display: none;` or `visibility: hidden;` on `figcaption`, `figcaption a`, or `figcaption a img`, should be working but it won't. While testing I removed the JavaScript to see if that had any effect and it didn't. I also added `id="playlist"` to `figcaption` and nothing worked.

Comment: Okay, I think I've figured out the problem. I'm going to post a new answer. Hopefully it will help.